# Use a Variable as a File

Tags: python, file, variables, python-3.x

This is probably a stretch.  I have a def (or function) that takes a file name, opens the file and performs action on the file content.  Is there a way in Python to use a variable in place of the file name?  In other words give a string or list file attributes.

```
def Albert(fname):
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    for i in f.readline():
        print(i)
#Main
Collins = 'Blues Guitar\n'
Albert(Collins)
```

Comment: Why would it be a stretch? That's exactly how it works. Your only problem is that your `Collins` string has a newline in it, which is not valid in a filename.

Comment: But 'Collins' is not a file name, it is a string that contains 'Blues Guitar\n'.  I would like the contents of the variable 'Collins' treated as the contents of a file.  I'm having trouble expressing this.

Comment: You want an in-memory file object with the *contents* being dictated by the variable. You did indeed not make that clear. In that case your question is a dupe of [Using Python, how do I to read/write data in memory like I would with a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1883326)

Comment: If you simply want to iterate over all lines in the String there is no need to use `StringIO` as recommended by the linked question. Just use `mystring.split("\n")` to get a list of the lines in the String, and iterate over that list.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Martijn.  I will have to move f = open(fname, 'r') outside of Albert(fname) -

```
def Albert(fname):

    while True:
        onechar = fname.read()
        if not onechar:
            break
        else:
            print(onechar, end = '')
    print()

#Main
import io

#stringIO mode
Collins = io.StringIO('Blues Guitar')
Albert(Collins)

#fileIO mode
fname = open('infile.txt', 'r')
Albert(fname) #where infile.txt containes 'Blues Guitar'

#Output
Blues Guitar 
Blues Guitar
```

But that goes a long way and prevents rewriting my actual def!

Comment: Remove the `.readlines()`. It reads the file into memory first which is not neccessary. (The difference would be visible only with huge files.) You can also test the type and/or the attributes of the passed `fname` and decide whether to `open` it inside the function, or whether to wrap it into `io.StringIO`.

Comment: Your right.  I changed fname.readlines() to fname.getvalue().  fname is of type string.

Comment: More code added to show basic idea.